# Trying to install Firebase for Google Analytics

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am trying to install Firebase for Google Analytics and I'm getting an error message:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseCore":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    FirebaseCore (= 3.6.0)

  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Core (= 4.3.0) was resolved to 4.3.0, which depends on
      FirebaseCore (= 4.0.8)

Specs satisfying the `FirebaseCore (= 3.6.0), FirebaseCore (= 4.0.8)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Is this just due to my Podfile.lock? Would deleting it solve this issue?

I'm trying to run an updated version of Firebase because the default version (which is much older) is causing Xcode 9 to crash.

```
target 'Candy' do
    pod 'Firebase/Core', '4.3.0'

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.2'
        end
    end
end
```

For reference, I'm on Swift 3.2 and I am trying to go based on this documentation by [Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/start)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently to get rid of the `Podfile.lock` which is generated on `pod install`, you need to run `pod update`.